# How to secure a leaning pine tree?

Tags: trees

I'm considering to buy a piece of land with an old pine tree. Unfortunately the tree is leaning to the side as you can see on the pictures.

[image]
[image]

My question is whether there is any way to secure the tree so it doesn fall in the neighbours. The tree is one of the reasons I want to buy the land so I'd rather keep it.

Comment: Look closely at the ground around the base of the tree, and for a meter or two out in every direction. Look for any signs that the ground has raised or dipped in places, or any hollow spots, with roots on top and empty space underneath. Those would be signs that the tree is starting to tip over. If it goes, it might damage the foundation of the house when the roots come out. Also inspect the foundation of the house, inside and out, especially near the corner closest to the tree.

Comment: I think landscaping is not a good reason to buy a house ; landscaping grows, changes and dies .  It looks like a spruce.

Comment: @csk, no visible uprooting around the tree.

Answer (score 3):

No, not really, and I'm not sure it's a problem anyway, so long as the tree seems healthy, so unless there are signs of fungus or softness, peeling bark or soggy oozing areas on the trunk somewhere. From the photograph showing the whole tree, it looks like the upper parts of the tree are relatively upright, compared to the trunk lower down. It will have grown like this when it was young because it would have been heading for the light - the proximity of the building behind meant the only way to do that was to bend at an angle to escape that and the lack of light it causes. But once it was out in the light, it looks as if it then adjusted its growth till it grew upwards, correcting itself because it was able to do so.

Comment: That was my way of thinking. But woman that was there when tree was planted, claimed that it grew upright and at some point bent itself. I don't know how much her recollection is trustworthy though. Do you think that is even possible?

Comment: From the way it appears in the photo, its likely it bent over as it became a sapling, so maybe she means it was upright initially - but in reality, I cannot tell the distance from the base of the tree to the building - in the photo, it looks very, very close indeed. If its a good eight to ten feet away from the building, in the open, then my theory about why its leaning is likely inaccurate, though we don't know what else was growing round/near it back then. There's no evidence of soil disruption at the base, which might have indicated the tree was actually leaning/moving much more recently.